# Azure Free Website and free Bandwidth

Tags: azure

On the Azure website, i found the following details for Windows Azure Website (Free instance)

> With the Windows Azure Web Sites free instance model, you will receive the following at no charge:

- 10 free web sites per sub region* on the AzureWebSites.net domain
- 165 MB of outbound data per day per sub region, up to 5 GB per region**
- 1 GB of storage per sub region (shared by all web sites)
- 20 MB of a third-party MySQL database per sub region for the first 12 months

> Each Windows Azure offer includes at least 5 GB of outbound data transfers per region per month at no charge. Data transfers utilized for other services besides Web Sites will be applied against the amount included in your offer.

Now, since the 5GB offer that is included inside this offer will expire at the end of june 2013, will there still be the free 165MB per day? This is important to estimate the costs of my project.

Kind regards
Tom

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, it is a question about Azure payment plans.

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental point here is, there are several offers / subscription types in Azure like BizSpark, MSDN, Free Trial, etc. Each has different slabs of `free out-bandwidth`. For example BizSpark come with 40 GB of free out bandwidth and Free Trial might be having 5GB of free out bandwidth.

5 GB limit is for all the services apart from **Azure Websites running in free** mode like Azure Cloud Services, Azure Storage Blob etc. The Azure Websites, Free mode will be having having the limit of 165 MB per day for that particular website. Check here to find out [What happens when exceeding daily download limit 165MB](http://navcode.info/2012/11/06/azure-websites-free-mode-what-happens-when-exceeding-daily-download-limit-165mb)

To make it short, 165 MB limit and the 5 GB limit are different. On a different note, if you exceed the out bandwidth free limit, it works out 12 cents per GB for US & EU data centers and 19 cents for Asian Data Centers.

Comment: This Error 403 will happen if you reached the bandwidth limit: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/01/05/azure-web-apps-error-403-this-web-app-is-stopped/ ... I will wait 24hr and try again, hopefully the bandwidth quota is daily.